# how to add a hidden type input to wp admin login form programmatically

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I want to write a wordpress plugin that custom the wp admin login form.
I want to add a hidden type input to the form.
please guide me to do this. thanks

Comment: Please provide more information - show us your plugin code and what you've done so far.  WP Stack Exchange is intended to answer specific technical questions for users.  What you've done here is basically ask for someone to provide you with a tutorial. Tutorials like this already exist: https://pippinsplugins.com/creating-custom-front-end-registration-and-login-forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook the [login_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_form/) action:

```
/**
 * Fires following the 'Password' field in the login form.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 */
do_action( 'login_form' );
```

which is called between the password box and the 'remember me?' checkbox, and write out your hidden input field there, e.g.

```
function wpse_366921_hidden_login_field() {
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden-login-field" value="1" />
    <?php
}
add_action( 'login_form', 'wpse_366921_hidden_login_field', 10, 0 );
```